# Keras AI training on Incorrect Data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, artificial-intelligence

I'm using Keras to predict cryptocurrency prices, but it's not training with the correct data. My intent is to divide my data into x_inputs and y_inputs. The x_inputs should be what the model uses to predict, and the y_inputs should be the expected values of those predictions. However, this is not happening correctly.

This is the relevant code I have written:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Order_Book.csv', sep=',', header=None)
df.drop(0, inplace=True)

drops = np.arange(101,len(df),101)

Prices = df[5][drops]
Prices = Prices.to_numpy()
Prices = Prices.astype(float)

df.drop(drops, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

bids = np.zeros((len(df), 2))
bids[:,0] = df[2]
bids[:,1] = df[3]

asks = np.zeros((len(df), 2))
asks[:,0] = df[4]
asks[:,1] = df[5]

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.95
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)

history = 1

Training_input = np.zeros((int(len(bids)/(history*100)), history * 400))

for i in range(0, int(len(bids)/(history*100))):
    for j in range(0,(history*100)):
        
        Training_input[i,4*j] = bids[j + i*(history*100), 0]
        Training_input[i,4*j+1] = bids[j + i*(history*100), 1]
        
        Training_input[i,4*j+2] = asks[j + i*(history*100), 0]
        Training_input[i,4*j+3] = asks[j + i*(history*100), 1]      


minimum = np.min(np.append(bids[:,0],asks[:,0]))
maximum = np.max(np.append(bids[:,0], asks[:,0]))
Training_input = (Training_input - minimum)/maximum
Prices = (Prices - minimum)/maximum

foresight = 1000
hindsight = 1
total_sight = hindsight + foresight


new_Training_input = Training_input[0:len(Training_input) - int(foresight) -3, :]
new_Prices = Prices[total_sight:len(Prices)-1:hindsight]

model = Sequential()

with tf.device("gpu:0"):
    model.add(Dense(4000, input_dim = (history*400), activation = 'sigmoid'))
    
    model.add(Dense(4000, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4000, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4000, activation = 'relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))    
  

    sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=.000001, decay = 1e-3)
    model.compile(loss="MAE", optimizer=sgd, metrics = 'MAE')
    model.fit(new_Training_input, new_Prices, epochs=20)
```

I apologize for the terrible variable names and overall poor code. What should be happening is that the code uses one order book to predict a price 1000 minutes out (that number was chosen to illustrate the problem, not to be realistic). In order to train for this, the first 1000 of my Price data points are discarded. Likewise then, the last 1000 order books must also be discarded, as they have no corresponding Price. The issue can be shown in this graph:

[image]

where black is the unaltered Price data, purple is the new_Price data, and red is the AI prediction. Clearly it can be seen that the AI is training toward the Price data and not the new_Price data. I have no idea why this is.